# using sup of an unbounded function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Is what I'm doing valid if we don't have any information on boundedness of $f$ or $f_n$?

let $X$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative integrable functions, $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. on $ X$.
This is true that
$$\left|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu\right| \leq \sup |f_n-f|\ \mu(X).$$

Set $X$ is under my control, so I want to say I can make it as small as a measure zero set, $\epsilon=\frac{\epsilon_0}{\sup\ |f_n-f|}$ in this case, and on that I don't need to care if $f_n \nrightarrow f$ because:

$$\left|\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu\right| \leq \sup |f_n-f| \times \frac{\epsilon_0}{\sup\ |f_n-f|}= \epsilon_0$$

Comment: $\infty / \infty=?$

Comment: I know, that's my problem! But can't I cancel them with each other?

Comment: You can probably rewrite the problem so that it does not occur. But the expression is simply meaningless.

Comment: If they are integrable, maybe the $L_1$ norm is better choice than $\sup$. (I guess in the 'almost everwhere' context, $\sup$ is meant the $L_\infty$ norm, no?)

Comment: What if $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what has been explained to you in the comments: $X=(0,1)$, $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(X)$, $\mu=\mathrm{Leb}$, $f_n:x\mapsto1/(n\sqrt{x})$. You might want to see what happens to the statements you try to prove, in this case. First, what is the function $f$? Next, what is $\|f_n-f\|_\infty$? Hence...